# Transferring Kubernetes cluster to other project include PVC

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a problem to migrate kubernetes cluster to other google project, not so familiar with GKE. Assuming my cluster is k8s-prod-xyz in xyz-proj project.

Now, i have a new project called xyz-new-proj and the Kubernetes cluster is still empty. I want to move or migrate the k8s-prod-xyz from xyz-proj to xyz-new-proj.

Node, PVC, Services, etc should be transfered or migrated. Have you guys experienced this case ? Or should i create new Kubernetes cluster in new project and then run the deployment from zero ?

Comment: learn more about `snapshot` to do such task

Comment: @kamol-hasan do you have any article related to its ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense as you are not allowed to create new GKE cluster using your existing Compute Engine VMs snapshots. It would be possible if you want to migrate a cluster which was set by yourself using Google Compute Engine VMs but it is not the case with GKE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GKE** feature **Clone an existing cluster** (however this works only within the same project) along with **Heptio Velero** tool. I guess the solution described in [this](https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-kubernetes-engine-cluster-migration-with-velero-4a140b018f32) article is currently the fastest and most convenient way of performing such migration.