# How to duplicate a kubernetes workload on gcp?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

I have 2 namespaces in my kubernetes cluster: development and production. I'm currently adding a third namespace: staging.

I'm NOT using terraform with which this task would have been supposedly simpler.

I'm looking for solutions within the GCP ecosystem to provision a workload in the staging namespace with all the environment variables and configurations of the development namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57307373/11714114). Unfortunately there is no ready solution for that within GCP, especially if you want to migrate workload from the existing cluster between different namespaces. However you can use for that purpose **Heptio Velero**. It's nicely described in [this](https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-kubernetes-engine-cluster-migration-with-velero-4a140b018f32) article.

Comment: Nah, my requirement is different. Heptio wont be useful for my case

Comment: Could you describe then what are your requirements in more detail ?

Comment: I want to clone a workload. Surprisingly GCP doesnt have that feature although there's the feature of cloning a cluster.

Comment: What are actually your reasons for not using tools like Heptio Velero ? It can be used to migrate workloads as well as other kubernetes cluster resources. Yes, GCP doesn't have such feature, that's why I would recommend to use for that an external tool like Heptio Velero. If you were able to find any other solution, please share it here as it might be useful for others.